# Database procedure won't run

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have to make a procedure for a database where you pass in a parameter to this procedure. It than takes that parameter you passed in, deletes the invoice with the same code or matching code. It than will update another table which has customer balance in it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE invoiceDelete(IN temp_code CHAR(4))
    BEGIN
    UPDATE customer
        DELETE FROM invoice WHERE INV_NUMBER = temp_code
        SET customer.CUS_BALANCE = customer.CUS_BALANCE + OLD.INV_TOTAL
        WHERE customer.CUS_CODE = OLD.CUS_CODE;
    END;
```

Comment: Old / new are for triggers only, you cannot use them in stored procs.

Answer (score 0):

Old / new are for triggers only, you cannot use them in stored procs. Also, you cannot mix update and delete.

First you need to update the balance of the customer (unless you do that in a trigger) using a traditional update statement. Then you delete the invoice.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE invoiceDelete(IN temp_code CHAR(4))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE customer INNER JOIN invoice ON customer.CUS_CODE = invoice.CUS_CODE
        SET customer.CUS_BALANCE = customer.CUS_BALANCE + invoice.INV_TOTAL
        WHERE invoice.INV_NUMBER = temp_code;
        DELETE FROM invoice WHERE INV_NUMBER = temp_code;
    END
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. And ill have too look more into it to understand, thanks.